# Access MassTransit ConsumeContext in MSDI IServiceCollection.AddTransient service

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, masstransit

We need to access a header in our `ConsumeContext` when adding a transient service.
We have been using `IHttpContextAccessor` previously to get the headers for a normal http request, and we now need to do similarly for our event consumers.
How would we go about accessing the headers for a consumed event when using MassTransit, when setting up our dependencies/services?

```cs
services.TryAddTransient<ISapService>(provider =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();    
    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(
        "x-plant-id",
        out var plantHeader
    );

    return new SapService(plantHeader);
});
```

Comment: What is the current problem? Is an error being thrown? Chances are that the event consumer is being invoked outside of a request scope which would make the HttpContext access problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works with *transient* services, but MassTransit does support [scoped filters](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html). They're resolved within the consumer scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`SendFilter`](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/middleware/scoped#usesendfilter) and use it while registering `MassTransit` in your startup.

```
  public class MySendFilter<T> :
    IFilter<SendContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MySendFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
      
    public async Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
    {
        if(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-plant-id", out var plantHeader)) 
        {
             context.Headers.Set("x-plant-id", plantHeader);
        }

        await next.Send(context);
    }
      
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
}
```

and now you should add your `MySendFilter` type to `MassTransit` :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {        
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
              cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(MySendFilter<>), context);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

With this filter, you can add your `x-plant-id` to every events header you sent.

When you consume those events, in your consumer, you can use `ConsumeContext` to get that `x-plant-id` from header. It would be something like that :

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext context)
{
   if(context.Headers.TryGetHeader("x-plant-id", out object plantHeader))
   {
      // your logic
   }
}
```

This seems working to me but it is not tested.